# Proof that L∈RE by building an enumerator

Tags: turing-machines, nfa

By definition: `A language is Turing-recognizable if and only if some enumerator enumerates it`

> Given Lmn = {< M,N > | L(M) ∩ L(N) ≠ ∅, where M is a basic Turing machine, and N is an NFA}
>
> Prove that Lmn ∈ RE by building an enumerator that enumerates it.

First of all, we probably should convert `N` to a `DFA`, to determine whether `N` `Accept` or `Reject` the input.

We know nothing about `M`, so it can halt after `X` steps, or loop infinitely, so how can we meet the restriction of `L(M) ∩ L(N) ≠ ∅`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to covert NFA into DFA. As it is not possible to know if a Turing machine will stop, we could do the same with NFA, too.

First, it is decidable to check a given string is encoding of a TM or not. The same is true for NFA, too. Also you could easily define an ordering for strings in an alphabet such as empty string, a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, ...

The enumerator could be define like this.

1. Run for m = 1,2,...,infinity
2. Get the first m^th string in the alphabet.
3. Check if it is a valid TM. Go to step 4 else go to step 1.
4. If it is a valid TM Run for n = 1,2,..,m. When we reach m, go to step 1.
5. Get the first n^th string in the alphabet
6. Check if it is a valid NFA, if not go to step 4.
7. Simulate both TM and NFA for all of the first m strings in the alphabet for at most m steps. If both of them accepts the same string, print that `<TM, NFA>`
8. Go to step 4

This machine will print all `<TM, NFA>` if they accept the same string `(L(M) ∩ L(N) ≠ ∅)` at some point.